# How to change output format of getFullYear() method in the function for date

Tags: javascript, string, date

I have on output the date format - 21.01.2012. I must change the getFullYear() method of date on output so that only the last two digits of the date are displayed. Roughly speaking, I need to cut out a millennium and a century, and have on output only year like - "01", "10", "17" ...

Cheers!

```
function formatDate(d) {

return (String(d.getDate()).replace(/^(.)$/, "0$1") +'.'+ 
String(d.getMonth()).replace(/^(.)$/, "0$1") + '.' + 
String(d.getFullYear()).replace(/^(.)$/, "0$1"));
}

var d = new Date(2012, 01, 21); 

console.log(formatDate(d))
```

Comment: `String(d.getFullYear()).slice(-2)`?

Comment: @Li357 oh god. Yep, you're right! So simple. Thank you buddy!

Comment: You can use a moment library , that's have a more options for date format https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Bassam Yes, I know. But I can not use any libraries. Thank you.

Comment: Months are zero indexed, you need to add one: `('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)`. ;-)